# Ripple: List of currency issuer addresses

Tags: ripple, cryptocurrency

I'd like to set up trust lines on my ripple account for several currencies including BTC, ETH, ETC, DSH, BCH, XLM, etc.

Where is the master list of issuers per currency?

So far I've only been able to establish a trust line on BTC from Bitstamp, because their address was public: https://www.bitstamp.net/ripple.txt

Answer (score 0):

Found a list from February 2018:

https://www.xrpchat.com/topic/19176-current-active-gateways-on-xrp-ledger/

Answer (score 0):

There is now a token list available here:

https://xrpl.services/tokens

and as API:

https://api.xrpldata.com/api/v1/tokens

the API is refreshed every ~30 minutes